# How can I test a decimal for null?

Tags: c#, .net, null, decimal

I've got this code intended to convert null decimal vals to a "zero" value:

```
decimal paymentTot = TryConvertToDecimal(boxPaymentAmount.Text);
if ((null == paymentTot) || (paymentTot < 0))
{
    paymentTot = 0M; // or simply 0?
}

private decimal TryConvertToDecimal(String incoming)
{
    decimal result = 0.0M;
    try
    {
        result = Convert.ToDecimal(incoming);
    }
    catch
    {
        ; // nada
    }
    return result;
}
```

It compiles, but I get this warning: "The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'decimal' is never equal to 'null' of type 'decimal?'"

I don't grok just what it's trying to tell me. What sort of test do I need to appease the warning emitter and, more importantly, see to it that my code can equate to 'true' when that is the intent?

Comment: `decimal` is a value type and can never be `null`.  Are you wanting the result of `TryConvertToDecimal` to be `null` if the parse fails?

Comment: No, I want it to return 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`decimal` is a value type and it can't be null.

If you want to have a nullable decimal then use `Nullable<decimal>` or `decimal?` which is a wrapper on `decimal` type, *(it is still a value type though)*.

See: [`Nullable<T> Structure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can also have your method for parsing as:

```
private Nullable<decimal> TryConvertToDecimal(String incoming)
{
    Nullable<decimal> returnValue = null;
    decimal result;
    if (decimal.TryParse(incoming, out result))
    {
        returnValue = result;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

*Also* it is better to use `decimal.TryParse` if you are going to ignore the exception in parsing.

Comment: Note that `decimal?` is also a value type. The important thing is that `decimal` is a non-nullable value type.

Answer (score 2):

You possibly want to return a [Nullable<decimal>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) (shorthand `decimal?`) from `TryConvertToDecimal` because decimal is a non-nullable value type.

```
private decimal? TryConvertToDecimal(String incoming)
{
    try
    {
        return Convert.ToDecimal(incoming);
    }
    catch
    {
       return null;
    }
}

var paymentTot = TryConvertToDecimal(boxPaymentAmount.Text);
if (!paymentTot.HasValue || paymentTot.Value < 0)
{
    paymentTot = 0;
}
```

Note however that by convention `TryXXX` functions return `bool` and use an `out` argument to return the parsed value upon success. One of these built in to the Framework is [decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) which you might want to use instead:

```
decimal paymentTot;
if(!decimal.TryParse(boxPaymentAmount.Text, out paymentTot) || paymentTot < 0)
    paymentTot = 0;
```

will default to 0 if the parsing fails *or* if the parsed value is < 0, as specified in your question. I would suggest this is most likely the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You don't Need your own Converter for this, use this instead:

```
decimal paymentTot;
if(!decimal.TryParse(boxPaymentAmount.Text, out paymentTot))
    paymentTot = 0;
```